# open()/Path.open(): only create the file on actual writing

Tags: python

Is there a way to "lazy" open a file in Python?

If I do `Path("my_path").open("wb")`, the file will be created and be empty until I write on it. What I want is for the file to not be created until I actually call the write() function on it.

In my specific case, I am [opening a streaming request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16694907) and heuristically determining the filetype from the first chunk, and if I don't open the file before iterating through the chunks I'll have to open and close the handler continuously. Right now I have to unlink the file and open a separate one if I determine that the url's extension is wrong, but I was looking for a more elegant solution.

Comment: Sure you could write e.g. a file wrapper that does that, but there's no built-in lazy opening in Python.

Comment: You could check if `os.path.exists("my_path")` and then open file if it true. Or you can check `Path("my_path").exists()`

Comment: It's not really clear what problem you hope to solve this way. How long are you planning to wait? Why not just open the file at the time that you need to start writing? It seems like you want to pass around an object that represents an unopened file - why not just pass around the `Path`?

Comment: Why not opening just before `write `?

Comment: My scenario is the following: I open a requests.get(url, stream=True) object and [write the chunks to a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16694907), however I do not know the correct filetype for sure beforehand. I would like to analyze the first chunk with a mime library, and if the actual filetype is different (for example, a png served as a jpg) then I want to rename the destination and save to there instead. The file must be open before I start looping around the chunks, otherwise I need to open/close at every chunk. Right now I'm forced to also delete the destination.

Comment: Create an object that looks and acts like a file but only does the open later. There's nothing of the sort built-in, but it's easy enough to write one yourself.

Comment: @ihatenginx You could have added that to your original post! :) You could start writing chunks to an `io.BytesIO()`, and when you have enough to write to disk, open the file, use `shutil.copyfileobj()` to write the bytesio's contents there and keep writing to the disk?

Comment: BTW, I agree with AKX that the description of the underlying use case would be better off as part of the question than in a comment.

Comment: I've updated the question with the use case. Can I drop the first chunks to the bytesio object, and then once i'm done determining the extension, dump the object to a file and resume writing the rest of the chunks to the file? because I'd accept that as a solution.